# Bug with lucida fonts in beamer

Tags: beamer

I've got a problem with math formulas in Beamer with Lucida fonts.
Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lucidabr} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
$x^{a_n}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It seems that the underscore n in exponent that cause trouble

Comment: You might want to look up `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` in the beamer manual. As beamer is special just loading a font package might not work as expected, hence this special theme.

Comment: What is the problem? It appears that all three characters are from the LucidaSans-Italic font as expected.